# Is there an error prone way to exclude certain properties from struct during equality comparison without writting our own == function?

Tags: ios, swift

We like the auto equality behavior of struct, by just simply conform `Equatable` protocol.

Sometimes, we would like to exclude some properties out from struct equality comparison.

Currently, this is the method we are using.

```
struct House: Equatable {
    var field_0: String
    var field_1: String
    ...
    var field_50: String

    static func == (lhs: House, rhs: House) -> Bool {
        if lhs.field_0 != rhs.field_0 { return false }
        if lhs.field_1 != rhs.field_1 { return false }
        ...
        if lhs.field_48 != rhs.field_48 { return false }
        // Ommit field_49
        if lhs.field_50 != rhs.field_50 { return false }

        return true
    }
}
```

But, such methodology is pretty error prone, especially when we add in new field in the struct.

Is there a way to exclude certain properties fields from equality comparison, without writing our own == function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to exclude certain properties fields from equality comparison, without writing our own `==` function?

No. At present, the only alternative to automatic synthesis of Equatable conformance is good old fashioned writing code.

Answer (score 9):

There is a solution using Swift Property Wrapper feature actually. It's described [here](https://medium.com/@dhavalshreyas/ignore-variables-for-equatable-conformance-in-swift-2f489fab76d9).

Basically what you need is to define next property wrapper

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EquatableNoop<Value>: Equatable {
    var wrappedValue: Value

    static func == (lhs: EquatableNoop<Value>, rhs: EquatableNoop<Value>) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

And use it like next

```
struct Test: Equatable {
    var a: Int

    @EquatableNoop
    var b: () -> Void
}
```

Comment: This is clever. I was able to adapt it for Hashable as well.